# How to take numeric variables from different functions, insert them into equation, and output answer into html

Tags: javascript, html, variables, global-variables

I'm new to Javascript. I am having trouble understanding how to access variables so that I can input them into an equation and output the answer back into html.

The html:

```
<body>

    <div onclick="firstq(100)">100</div>
    <div onclick="firstq(150)">150</div>
    <div onclick="firstq(300)">300</div>

    <div id="results"></div>

</body>
```

The javascript:

```
function firstq(one) {
    switch(one) {
        case 100:
        var answer1 = 100;
        break; 
        case 150:
        var answer1 = 150;
        break; 
        case 300:
        var answer1 = 300;
        break;       
    }
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="The total is = "+answer1;
}
```

It works fine until this point and will show the output, but what I really want to do is make an equation built from different answers, and then output it after clicking another div, some way similar to:

more html:

```
<div onclick="secondq(5)">5</div>
<div onclick="secondq(10)">10</div>
<div onclick="secondq(20)">20</div>

<div id="thebutton" onclick="clickedthebutton()'>Click me!</div>
```

more js:

```
function firstq(two) {
    switch(two) {
        case 5:
        var answer2 = 5;
        break; 
        case 10:
        var answer2 = 10;
        break; 
        case 20:
        var answer2 = 20;
        break;       
    }
}

function clickedthebutton() {
    var theanswer = answer1*answer2;
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="The total is = "+theanswer;
}
```

I'm not sure if the variables need to be made global, or what I'm overlooking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you well, you would want to do something like this:

```
var calc = (function(){
    var answer1 = 0,
        answer2 = 0;

    function firstq(one) {
        answer1 = 300;
    }

    function secondq(two) {
        answer2 = two;
    }

    function clickedthebutton() {
        var theanswer = answer1*answer2;
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="The total is = "+theanswer;
    }

     return {
        firstq: firstq,
        secondq: secondq,
        clickedthebutton: clickedthebutton,
    }

}());
```

```
<div onclick="calc.firstq(100)">100</div>
<div onclick="calc.firstq(150)">150</div>
<div onclick="calc.firstq(300)">300</div>

<div id="results"></div>

<div onclick="calc.secondq(5)">5</div>
<div onclick="calc.secondq(10)">10</div>
<div onclick="calc.secondq(20)">20</div>

<div id="thebutton" onclick="calc.clickedthebutton()'>Click me!</div>
```

Refrain from using html attributes to register the click events. It's better to attach your event in your JavaScript code; and most importantly, avoid introducing many variables into the global scope

Comment: I ran it and it worked. I see you removed the switches, I guess they were redundant so that made sense. I'm still struggling to understand why wrapping it in the calc function made it work. Thank you though!

Comment: well basically i use what is called the revealing module pattern. In essence, i declared one global variable (i.e. the module) which exposes only the bits that are needed; So we kept the answer1 and answer2.

Answer (score 0):

To declare global variable do inside your javascript tag:

```
var answer1;
var asnwer2;
```

I dont see a function mamed `secondq(two)` in your javascript code

Comment: Oops, I forgot to replace the firstq with secondq when I copied that piece.